# Битрикс - ЧПУ catalog.smart.filter

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите, возможно ли вырезать код свойства и параметры ЧПУ - `is-from-to-or` - из него же? И дополнение `/apply/`?

Поиск по форуму и поисковикам ничего не дал...
Колдую над классом компонента `smart.filter`, но безуспешно.

На данный момент так:

```
/catalog/sale_flats/filter/street-is-2-ya-sadovaya/apply/
```

А хочу, чтобы было так:

```
/catalog/sale_flats/filter/2-ya-sadovaya/
```

В классе 5 функций, которые за это отвечают, но не могу с ними разобраться...

```html
    public function searchProperty($items, $lookupValue)
    {
        foreach($items as $itemId => $arItem)
        {
            if (!$arItem["PRICE"])
            {
                $code = toLower($arItem["CODE"]);
                if ($lookupValue === $code)
                    return $itemId;
                if ($lookupValue == intval($arItem["ID"]))
                    return $itemId;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function searchValue($item, $lookupValue)
    {
        foreach($item as $itemId => $arValue)
        {
            if ($lookupValue === $arValue["URL_ID"])
                return $itemId;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public function convertUrlToCheck($url)
    {
        $result = array();
        $smartParts = explode("/", $url);
        foreach ($smartParts as $smartPart)
        {
            $item = false;
            $smartPart = preg_split("/-(from|to|is|or)-/", $smartPart, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
            foreach ($smartPart as $i => $smartElement)
            {
                if ($i == 0)
                {
                    if (preg_match("/^price-(.+)$/", $smartElement, $match))
                        $itemId = $this->searchPrice($this->arResult["ITEMS"], $match[1]);
                    else
                        $itemId = $this->searchProperty($this->arResult["ITEMS"], $smartElement);

                    if ($itemId)
                        $item = &$this->arResult["ITEMS"][$itemId];
                    else
                        break;
                }
                elseif ($smartElement === "from")
                {
                    $result[$item["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_NAME"]] = $smartPart[$i+1];
                }
                elseif ($smartElement === "to")
                {
                    $result[$item["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_NAME"]] = $smartPart[$i+1];
                }
                elseif ($smartElement === "is" || $smartElement === "or")
                {
                    $valueId = $this->searchValue($item["VALUES"], $smartPart[$i+1]);
                    if (strlen($valueId))
                    {
                        $result[$item["VALUES"][$valueId]["CONTROL_NAME"]] = $item["VALUES"][$valueId]["HTML_VALUE"];
                    }
                }

            }
            unset($item);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function makeSmartUrl($url, $apply, $checkedControlId = false)
    {
        $smartParts = array();

        if ($apply)
        {
            foreach($this->arResult["ITEMS"] as $PID => $arItem)
            {   
                $smartPart = array();
                //Prices
                if ($arItem["PRICE"])
                {
                    if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"] || $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"])
                    {
                        if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"])
                            $smartPart["from"] = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"];
                        if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"])
                            $smartPart["to"] = $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"];
                    }
                }

                if ($smartPart)
                {
                    array_unshift($smartPart, toLower("price-".$arItem["CODE"]));
                    $smartParts[] = $smartPart;
                }
                
            }

            foreach($this->arResult["ITEMS"] as $PID => $arItem)
            {
                $smartPart = array();
                if ($arItem["PRICE"])
                    continue;

                //Numbers && calendar == ranges
                if (
                    $arItem["PROPERTY_TYPE"] == "N"
                    || $arItem["DISPLAY_TYPE"] == "U"
                )
                {
                    if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"] || $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"])
                    {
                        if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"])
                            $smartPart["from"] = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"];
                        if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"])
                            $smartPart["to"] = $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach($arItem["VALUES"] as $key => $ar)
                    {
                        if (
                            (
                                $ar["CHECKED"]
                                || $ar["CONTROL_ID"] === $checkedControlId
                            )
                            && strlen($ar["URL_ID"])
                        )
                        {
                            $smartPart[] = $ar["URL_ID"];
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($smartPart)
                {
                    if ($arItem["CODE"])
                        array_unshift($smartPart, toLower($arItem["CODE"]));
                    else
                        array_unshift($smartPart, $arItem["ID"]);

                    $smartParts[] = $smartPart;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$smartParts)
            $smartParts[] = array("clear");

        return str_replace("#SMART_FILTER_PATH#", implode("/", $this->encodeSmartParts($smartParts)), $url);
    }

    public function encodeSmartParts($smartParts)
    {
        
        foreach ($smartParts as &$smartPart)
        {
            $urlPart = "";
            foreach ($smartPart as $i => $smartElement)
            {
                
                if (!$urlPart){
                    $urlPart .= urlencode($smartElement);
                }
                elseif ($i == 'from' || $i == 'to'){
                    $urlPart .= urlencode('-'.$i.'-'.$smartElement);
                }
                elseif ($i == 1){
                    $urlPart .= urlencode('-is-'.$smartElement);
                }   
                else{
                    $urlPart .= urlencode('-or-'.$smartElement);
                }
            }
            $smartPart = $urlPart;
        }
        unset($smartPart);
        return $smartParts;

    }
```

Может быть, кто-то более опытный подскажет?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, такое

```
/catalog/sale_flats/filter/2-ya-sadovaya/
```

будет работать некорректно, т.к. чтобы понять фильтру по какому свойству идет фильтрация будет болезненно и скрипт будет выполняться дольше.

Тебе надо переписать все функции к такому виду

```
/catalog/sale_flats/filter/street/2-ya-sadovaya/#PROP_CODE#/#PROP_FILTER_VALUE#/
```

и так далее.

Comment: еще ты должен учитывать, того что свойства могут быть выбраны несколько, т.е. тут `#PROP_FILTER_VALUE#` надо будет сделать так `#PROP_FILTER_VALUE#-and-#PROP_FILTER_VALUE#-and-#PROP_FILTER_VALUE#`

Comment: желательно компонент `catalog.smart.filter` скопируй в `local` и там работай. Куда копать указал, дальше работа за вами, т.е. реализация.

Comment: Не пишите комментарии, лучше  улучшайте  ответ кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/847271/edit).

Answer (score 0):

1. Кастомизировать catalog.smart.filter. Написать свои convertUrlToCheck и makeSmartUrl.
2. Кастомизировать компонент каталога. Когда вы уберете apply, он будет определять страницу фильтра как страницу элемента или секции. Это надо переопределить в component.php